# How to bulid a list of map data into hierarical-parent-child relation using java

Tags: java, java-stream

I have a list of data. I want to build it as parent-child relation using this JSON array:

```
[ 
  {"id":1, "parent_id": 1, "name": "Wood", "price": 0}, 
  {"id":2, "parent_id": 1, "name": "Mango", "price": 18}, 
  {"id":3, "parent_id": 2, "name": "Table", "price": 342}, 
  {"id":4, "parent_id": 2, "name": "Box", "price": 340}, 
  {"id":5, "parent_id": 4, "name": "Pencil", "price": 240}, 
  {"id":6, "parent_id": 0, "name": "Electronic", "price": 20}, 
  {"id":7, "parent_id": 6, "name": "TV", "price": 350}, 
  {"id":8, "parent_id": 6, "name": "Mobile", "price": 300}, 
  {"id":9, "parent_id": 8, "name": "Iphone", "price": 0}, 
  {"id":10, "parent_id": 9, "name": "Iphone 10", "price": 400}
]
```

I want to get the output for in this JSON hierarchical structure:

```
[ { "id": 1, "parent_id": 0, "name": "Wood", "price": 0, "children": [ { "id": 2, "parent_id": 1, "name": "Mango", "price": 18, "children": [ { "id": 3, "parent_id": 2, "name": "Table", "price": 342 }, { "id": 4, "parent_id": 2, "name": "Box", "price": 340, "children": [ { "id": 5, "parent_id": 4, "name": "Pencil", "price": 240 } ] } ] } ] }, { "id": 6, "parent_id": 0, "name": "Electronic", "price": 20, "children": [ { "id": 7, "parent_id": 6, "name": "TV", "price": 350 }, { "id": 8, "parent_id": 6, "name": "Mobile", "price": 300, "children": [ { "id": 9, "parent_id": 8, "name": "Iphone", "price": 0, "children": [ { "id": 10, "parent_id": 9, "name": "Iphone 10", "price": 400 } ] } ] } ] } ]
```

I have tried to tackle the problem, I didn't get the required output. I am getting a `NullPointerException`

Can you please help or point out the problem?

```
for (Map<String, Object> currentData : listData) {
            currentData.put("children", generateData(currentData, listData));
            List<Map<String, Object>> listOfChildrenData = new CopyOnWriteArrayList<Map<String, Object>>();
            listOfChildrenData = objectMapper.convertValue(currentData.get("children"),
                    new TypeReference<List<Map<String, Object>>>() {
                    });
            for (Map<String, Object> currentchild : listOfChildrenData) {
                Iterator<Map<String, Object>> iter = listData.iterator();
                System.out.println(currentchild);
                while (iter.hasNext()) {
                    Map<String, Object> curRemoveMap = iter.next();

                    if (currentchild.get("id") == curRemoveMap.get("id")) {
                        toRemove.add(currentchild);             
                    }
                }
            }
        }


public static List<Map<String, Object>> generateData(Map<String, Object> currentData,
            List<Map<String, Object>> listData) {
        List<Map<String, Object>> generateChild = new ArrayList<Map<String, Object>>();
        for (Map<String, Object> recurseChild : listData) {
            if (recurseChild.get("parent_id") == currentData.get("id")) {
                generateChild.add(recurseChild);
            }
        }
        return generateChild;
    }
```

Comment: Please include the stack trace and indicate the line which causes the exception.

Comment: A [mcve] would be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's create a `Product` class first, so it will help us solve the problem:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL) // Used to avoid "children": null
public class Product {
    private int id;
    private int parent_id;
    private String name;
    private int price;
    private List<Product> children;
}
```

Given `Product` objects, we can group products by their parent, then set for each parent its children:

```
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
List<Product> products = objectMapper.readValue(jsonStr, new TypeReference<List<Product>>() {});

Map<Integer, List<Product>> parentIdToChildren = products.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Product::getParent_id));
products.forEach(p -> p.setChildren(parentIdToChildren.get(p.getId())));

List<Product> root = parentIdToChildren.get(0); // 'parent_id = 0' means no parent
System.out.println(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(root));
```

Output (same as expected):

```
[{"id":1,"parent_id":0,"name":"Wood","price":0,"children":[{"id":2,"parent_id":1,"name":"Mango","price":18,"children":[{"id":3,"parent_id":2,"name":"Table","price":342},{"id":4,"parent_id":2,"name":"Box","price":340,"children":[{"id":5,"parent_id":4,"name":"Pencil","price":240}]}]}]},{"id":6,"parent_id":0,"name":"Electronic","price":20,"children":[{"id":7,"parent_id":6,"name":"TV","price":350},{"id":8,"parent_id":6,"name":"Mobile","price":300,"children":[{"id":9,"parent_id":8,"name":"Iphone","price":0,"children":[{"id":10,"parent_id":9,"name":"Iphone 10","price":400}]}]}]}]
```

Comment: Better to use `@JsonProperty("parent_id") private int parentId` so that it would follow the naming convention.